Почему выдает ошибку ('list' object has no attribute 'send_keys') при работе с selenium
пробовал ставить [0] перед send_keys, xpath id итд, ошибка не меняется
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
mail = 'login'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://appleid.apple.com/sign-in')

time.sleep(10)
cla = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/apple-auth/div/div[1]/div/sign-in/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span').send_keys(mail)
cla.send_keys(mail)

time.sleep(10)
browser.quit()


Написано же - потому что у списка нет метода send_keys().
